# Type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-queryset

Eu tenho uma view que importa algumas funções de um modelo, e quando eu importo o modelo dentro da view, tenho problema com o datetime.
A função que existe no modelo funciona perfeitamente, mas na view tenho erro. A função best_month é :

```py
    def best_month(cls):
        res = {}
        month_price = cls.objects.values_list('created_time__month').annotate(total=Sum('price'))
        if month_price:
            res['month'], res['price'] = max(month_price, key=lambda i: i[1])
            res['month_name'] = date(datetime.date(datetime.datetime.now().year, month=res['month'], day=1), 'F')
        return res
```

mas quando chamo para view :

```py
    
def dashboard(request):
    context = {'segment': 'index'}
    html_template = loader.get_template('account/dashboard.html')

    context.update(dict(Item.total_info()))
    context['best_month'] = Item.best_month()
    context['orders_month_report'], context['orders_month_report_labels'] = Item.orders_month_report()

    context['orders'], context['info'] = set_pagination(request, Item.objects.all().order_by('-id'), item_numer=10)
    if not context['orders']:
        messages.warning(request, context['info'])
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

```
Tenho o seguinte erro :
```

```
    
---> 71             res['month_name'] = date(datetime.date(datetime.datetime.now().year, month=res['month'], day=1), 'F')
     72         return res
     73

AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Answer (score 0):

Fala Chuck! Tudo bem?

Não consegui achar em seu código qual `import` você está realizando dentro da biblioteca do datetime. Acredito que o erro está na confusão do nome do módulo.

Para utilizar o `datetime.datetime`, você pode:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date = datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 23) 
>>> print(date)
2021-04-23 00:00:00
```

Como parâmetros, é possível utilizar `datetime.datetime(ano, mes, dia, hora, minuto, segundo, microsegundo, e info).`

Comment: Verdade, bem lembrado. Eu importei no models como :
```python
from datetime import datetime, date
```  e nas views eu importei como  
``` 
import datetime 
```